# Is it possible to do a grep with keywords stored in the array?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

Is it possible to do a grep with keywords stored in the array.

Here is the possible code snippet; how can I correct it?

```
args=("key1" "key2" "key3")

cat file_name |while read line
 echo $line | grep -q -w ${args[c]}
done
```

At the moment, I can search for only one keyword. I would like to search for all the keywords which is stored in *args* array.

Comment: While not really a solution, but cat is used to concatenate files, if there is only one file, use the input directive: 

while read line
 echo $line | grep -q -w ${args[c]}
done < file_name

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I am used to doing it by seeing other examples.. didnt realize it.. 
thanks a ton

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
args=("key1" "key2" "key3")
pat=$(echo ${args[@]}|tr " " "|")
grep -Eow "$pat" file
```

Or with the shell

```
args=("key1" "key2" "key3")
while read -r line
do
    for i in ${args[@]}
    do
        case "$line" in
            *"$i"*) echo "found: $line";;
        esac
    done
done <"file"
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use some bash expansion magic to prefix each element with -e and pass each element of the array as a separate pattern. This may avoid some precedence issues where your patterns may interact badly with the | operator:

```
$ grep ${args[@]/#/-e } file_name
```

The downside to this is that you cannot have any spaces in your patterns because that will split the arguments to grep. You cannot put quotes around the above expansion, otherwise you get "-e pattern" as a single argument to grep.

Answer (score 4):

This is one way:

```
args=("key1" "key2" "key3")
keys=${args[@]/%/\\|}      # result: key1\| key2\| key3\|
keys=${keys// }            # result: key1\|key2\|key3\|
grep "${keys}" file_name
```

**Edit:**

Based on **Pavel Shved's** suggestion:

```
( IFS="|"; keys="${args[*]}"; keys="${keys//|/\\|}"; grep "${keys}" file_name )
```

The first version as a one-liner:

```
keys=${args[@]/%/\\|}; keys=${keys// }; grep "${keys}" file_name
```

**Edit2:**

Even better than the version using `IFS`:

```
printf -v keys "%s\\|" "${args[@]}"; grep "${keys}" file_name
```

Comment: can you explain how your solution works? I am stuck at understanding the purpose of % in  your pattern args[@]/%/\\|

Comment: @Sharad: Look in the ]Bash Manual at Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) inn the next to last paragraph. The assignment in my example `keys=${args[@]/%/\\|}` says to replace (`/`) the end (`%`) of each element of the array (`args[@]`) with (`/`) a backslash and a pipe (`\\|`). So it adds those characters since the "end" (a `%` followed by no other characters to match) is just that - no characters are removed during the "replacement" in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I tend to use process substitution for everything. It's convenient when combined with `grep`'s `-f` option:

> Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.

(Depending on the context, you might even want to combine that with `-F`, `-x` or `-w`, etc., for awesome effects.)

So:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

t=(8 12 24)

seq 30 | grep -f <(printf '%s\n' "${t[@]}")
```

and I get:

```
8
12
18
24
28
```

I basically write a pseudo-file with one item of the array per line, and then tell `grep` to use each of these lines as a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
( IFS="|" ; grep --perl-regexp "${args[*]}" ) <file_name
```

searches the file for each keyword in an array.  It does so by constructing regular expression `word1|word2|word3` that matches any word from the alternatives given (in perl mode).

If I there is a way to join array elements into a string, delimiting them with *sequence* of characters (namely, `\|`), it could be done without perl regexp.

Comment: On my system, it's singular: `--perl-regexp`. Also, useless use of `cat`.

Comment: `( IFS ... grep ... file_name )` - no need for redirection. Does your `grep` really have an "s" in `--perl-regexp`?

Comment: @Dennis, no, it doesn't have "s", I pasted version with typo.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this;

```
cat file_name |while read line
for arg in ${args[@]}
do
echo $line | grep -q -w $arg}
done
done
```

not tested!

Comment: Well, I need to search for both the keywords at the same time something like ${args[*]} or with egrep with multiple keywords.

Any idea ?