# How to grep directory for keyword existence?

Tags: regex, shell

For example I have a /path/to/folder and want to see if it contains "keyword1", "keyword2" or "keyword3" and the result would be (when 2 are found):

```
/path/to/folder: keyword1 keyword3
```

I tried with options shown  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295361/is-it-possible-to-do-a-grep-with-keywords-stored-in-the-array)  but it doesn't work for folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo -n '/path/to/folder:'; for kw in {keyword1,keyword2,keyword3}; do grep -qr $kw /path/to/folder/; if [ $? == 0 ]; then echo -n " "$kw; fi; done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about keywords in filenames

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *keyword1* *keyword2* *keyword3*
do
  echo "$file"
done
```

if you are talking about finding those keywords in the files that are in your folder, you can use tools like `grep`

`grep -l -E "keyword1|keyword2|keyword3" *`

if you need to show which keywords are found

```
grep  -Eo "keyword1|keyword3|keyword2" *
```

Comment: It will almost do the trick except it doesn't output WHICH keywords were found.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E "keyword1|keyword3|keyword2" *
```

will return something like this:

> file.one:This text contains **keyword1**.
>   file.two:The **keyword2** can be found in this file.
>   file.six:This is a keyword enumeration: **keyword1**, **keyword2**, **keyword3**.